# Get-SPServer shows that all servers in the farm except itself need to be upgraded. Is there a problem?

Tags: 2013, search, powershell, psconfig

This morning I was reviewing the SharePoint Health Analyzer alerts and came across an error that one of my non content databases (Search) was "in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended."  I went ahead and ran `psconfigui` on one of my application servers which completed successfully.  Afterwards, I re-analyzed the warning, and everything cleared up.  One interesting thing I am noticing, however, is that when I run the `Get-SPServer | Where-Object {$_.NeedsUpgrade -eq $TRUE}` command, each server in the farm will return False for itself and show that all other servers are True.  Even the server that I ran `psconfigui` on will appear as needing an update according to any server in the farm that isn't itself.  Is this a problem?  What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try executing `(get-spfarm).buildversion` to force the servers to refresh their patch status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are behind the from the Microsoft CU then server will complain about the upgrade required. I.e you are Jan 2015 CU but MSFT release the Nov CU, in this case you are behind couple of cu.

It will not be a problem but i would install the latest CU and run config wizard if i am way behind.

Comment: That makes sense.  Isn't it best practice, though, to stay one CU behind the newest one to ensure there aren't any issues with the newest release?

Comment: Showing "Upgrade Required" is an indication that you have applied either a CU or Security Patch and have not run the Config Wizard.